# Are there any client side javascript libraries for displaying and editing word docs in a web page

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, ms-word

We have a requirement to display and provide editing functions for a Microsoft word document in a clients browser.

Everything has to be done in the browser. No launching of microsoft word is allowed using ActiveXObject malarky is allowed.

The data is very sensitive so we cannot use any third party services where the data leaves our server to get converted/embedded (this rules out Google Docs, Microsoft One Drive etc).

So far the only library we have found which fulfils only a part of the requirements is 
 http://viewerjs.org/. However this only allows viewing of the documents, no editing

We are developing on the JEE platform.

I have a feeling this really isn't possible on a browser using just client side libraries am I correct? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I never heard of any Javascript Libraries that would do what you ask. That would be theoratically possible, Google Docs is doing that (even if that's not open source). I'm the maintainer of DocxTemplater, a docx templating engine, that might be a workaround to your problem. https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

Comment: Cheers edi9999, we are all already using docx4j for doing the swapping on template parameters on the word document. What we were actually after was something to display (and edit) the word doc in the browser.

Oh yeah and to add to the fun, it's got to be free.

Got a horrible feeling we are gubbed :)

Comment: @MarkHanlon Did you ever get a solution to this. Am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible with Ace-Office. Unlike third party services like Google Docs, aceoffix is in your project which installed on your own server. Users edit document in browsers at client side and save all data back to the server.